# Need help reading data from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Can someone help me and attach a code snippet that can read "Temperature" data from firebase ?
[image]

log:
2019-03-30 15:41:14.959 1354-2862/guc.thermometer.mark10R I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:4 and remote module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:6
2019-03-30 15:41:14.959 1354-2862/guc.thermometer.mark10R I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.firebase_database, version >= 6

I tried this code, but it didn't work .

```
myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().getRoot();
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String name = dataSnapshot.child("Temprature").getValue().toString();
        tvinfo.setText(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: The first thing to do is to make sure you're not ignoring errors. `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`

Comment: See the error log first .

Comment: Have have you intialized firebaseInstance and database refrence.It will work .

Comment: can you show your error first ?????

Comment: please add log also

Comment: Using `Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());` is anything printed out in the logcat?

Comment: the only error i am having is Android Firebase DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor

Comment: permissions are true and play services is updated

Comment: 2019-03-30 15:41:14.959 1354-2862/guc.thermometer.mark10R I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:4 and remote module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:6
2019-03-30 15:41:14.959 1354-2862/guc.thermometer.mark10R I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.firebase_database, version >= 6

Comment: did you check your firebase database rules?

Comment: yes i did but nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = reference.child("thermometer/Temperature");
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                String temp = dataSnapshot.getvalue.toString()    
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
           //display error msg
        }
```

Comment: didn't work i even checked the permissions and they are all true

Comment: nvm found the error was a silly findviewbyid xD thanks tho